# Posting interactive content on wordpress with R

Tags: r, wordpress, r-markdown, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to post a Rmarkdown document to WordPress that also includes an interactive element (ggplotly graph) using the knit2wp package. I can post text and images OK but the interactive content doesn't work (see error message bellow). I tried using an iframe or the frameWidget {widgetframe} command with no success. I think the issue is that the content referenced in the iframe needs to be uploaded in the WordPress gallery as well.

Example code for publishing article:

```r
options(WordpressLogin = c(user = 'pasword'),
        WordpressURL = 'https://blog.site.com/xmlrpc.php')

knit2wp('test.Rmd',
        title = 'test',
        publish = FALSE,
        action = "newPost")
```

Example of a Rmarkdown file with interactive element:

````r
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g <- ggplot(cars, aes(dist, speed)) + geom_point()

ggplotly(g)
```

Some text
````

Error I get when I use iframe:

```r
## Error in path.expand(path): invalid 'path' argument
```

Any ideas how to post rmarkdown files with interactive content to wordpress using R?